# Image not showing with use of timers

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer

I am trying to add this picture of this car to go from left to right and back and forth from the screen, and the image is not showing up, and I am not sure if am going about this right. Also will the image overlap the frame from the original that this panel is sent too. Thank you for all the help, and I am new to OOP so sorry for all bad code practice ahead of time.

```
public class Animation extends JPanel {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Image carpic ;

int xpos =1;
int ypos =100;

Animation(){;
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    setBackground(Color.black);
    try {
        carpic = ImageIO.read(new File("car.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Graphics car = carpic.getGraphics();

    Timer timer = new Timer(1, null);

    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    timer.start();

    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            xpos += 10;
            if(xpos==200){
                xpos = 0;
                ypos+=100;

            }
            car.drawImage(carpic, xpos, ypos, null);
            repaint();
        }

    });
}}
```

Comment: You are drawing the image on top of itself (`car = carpic.getGraphics(); ... ; car.drawImage(carpic, xpos, ypos, null);`), not to the components' visible area. Instead you should modify the coordinates and call `repaint()` in the timer, and do the actual drawing in  `paintComponent()`.

Comment: So should I use the paintComponent() as a method as put my draw image inside? Im new to all this and I am little unsure on how all this works.

Comment: See [custom painting in swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) about how to do the drawing.